# Why is the characterset changing if starting Glassfish using php_exec compared to starting it in the console?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, glassfish, php53

I have created a PHP script to start/stop GlassFish server. In the PHP, I am using the [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) method to execute the start-domain and stop-domain commands.

To start the server

```
shell_exec("sudo -u root /usr/local/glassfish3/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1");
```

To stop the server

```php
shell_exec("sudo -u root /usr/local/glassfish3/bin/asadmin stop-domain domain1");
```

While the script does start and stop the server, there is an issue I can't figure out. The character encoding changes to something different and the special characters coming from the client requests are no longer formatted correctly.

Characters with correct charset

[image]

Characters with incorrect charset

[image]

Seems that the settings for UTF-8 are getting ignored and it falls back to a different charset what I believe to "ISO-8859-1".

domain.xml

```
<jdbc-connection-pool connection-validation-method="auto-commit" ...>
  <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

sun-web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Servlet 2.5//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_2_5-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/some-directory-war</context-root>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
  <!-- Change the default character encoding from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 -->
  <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
</sun-web-app>
```

During my investigation I found numerous articles stating to define the character set in the sun-web.xml (older version of glassfish - my case) but does not help.

> After some testing, I have noticed that if I login with www-data in the console, the default shell used is /bin/sh and starting the domain from that causes the same issue.
>   However, if I switch to /bin/bash, then it works.

Does anyone have a clue what could be the difference?

Any information on this will be much appreciated!

Comment: It'll be environment differences, probably `LANG`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the shell locale has an impact on how the GlassFish server interprets requests. I don't find it logical since the domain has its own settings file for that...

The following user comment actually helped: [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#78279)

```php
$locale = "en_US.UTF-8";
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, $locale);
putenv('LC_CTYPE=' . $locale);

shell_exec("sudo -u root /usr/local/glassfish3/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1");
```

It works like a charm!